# Deviation from expected value of mean distance between 2 points 'on ' a sphere

Tags: python, random, uniform-distribution

I was trying to verify the mean distance between 2 points in various 3-D and 2-D structures by taking average of multiple random cases. Almost all the time, I was getting a pretty good accuracy except for the case of  points on the surface of a sphere. My code uses Gaussian distribution inspired from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585975/how-to-generate-random-points-on-a-sphere) (see the second most up voted answer)

Here is the python code:

```
import math as m
from random import uniform as u
sum = 0
for i in range(10000):
    x1 = u(-1, 1)
    y1 = u(-1, 1)
    x2 = u(-1, 1)
    y2 = u(-1, 1)
    z1 = u(-1, 1)
    z2 = u(-1, 1)
    if x1 == y1 == z1 == 0:
        sum += m.sqrt((x2) ** 2 + (y2) ** 2 + (z2) ** 2)
    elif x2 == y2 == z2 == 0:
        sum += m.sqrt((x1) ** 2 + (y1) ** 2 + (z1) ** 2)
    else:
        x1 /= m.sqrt(x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2 + z1 ** 2)
        y1 /= m.sqrt(x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2 + z1 ** 2)
        z1 /= m.sqrt(x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2 + z1 ** 2)
        x2 /= m.sqrt(x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2 + z2 ** 2)
        y2 /= m.sqrt(x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2 + z2 ** 2)
        z2 /= m.sqrt(x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2 + z2 ** 2)
        sum += m.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2 + (z1-z2) ** 2)
print(sum/10000)
```

The expected value is 4/3 which is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167932/mean-distance-between-2-points-within-a-sphere)

Arguably the absolute difference is not very large. But the percentage deviation from expected value is around 1% on any run. On the other hand, in all other similar programs with other shapes and same number of random cases, the % deviation is around 0.05% on average.

Also, the value that the code returns is always less than 4/3. This is my major concern.

My guess is that I have implemented the algorithm in a wrong way. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

After realizing the mistake made in the previous method, I now, first use rejection sampling to get the points lying inside the sphere. This will ensure that after dividing the point vectors with their norms, the resulting unit vector distribution will be uniform. In spite of doing that, I am getting a different result, which is unexpectedly more deviated from expected than the previous one.
To be more precise, the limit approaches 1.25 with this algorithm.

Here is the code:

```
sum2 = 0
size = 0
for t in range(10000):  # Attempt 2
    x1 = u(-1, 1)
    y1 = u(-1, 1)
    x2 = u(-1, 1)
    y2 = u(-1, 1)
    z1 = u(-1, 1)
    z2 = u(-1, 1)
    if (x1**2 + y1**2 + z1**2)>1 or (x2**2 + y2**2 + z2**2)>1 or x1==y1==z1==0 or x2==y2==z2==0: continue
    size += 1
    x1 /= m.sqrt(x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2 + z1 ** 2)
    y1 /= m.sqrt(x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2 + z1 ** 2)
    z1 /= m.sqrt(x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2 + z1 ** 2)
    x2 /= m.sqrt(x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2 + z2 ** 2)
    y2 /= m.sqrt(x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2 + z2 ** 2)
    z2 /= m.sqrt(x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2 + z2 ** 2)
    sum2 += m.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2 + (z1 - z2) ** 2)
print(size)
print(sum2/size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial random values for the two points are contained within a cube, rather than a sphere. After scaling each vector by 1/length, the vectors are on the unit sphere, but they are not evenly distributed across the surface of the sphere.

You will tend to get more vectors near the corners of the cube, compared to the centre of each face. Since the vectors tend to cluster in regions, the average value of the distance between them is less than 4/3.

This will do the trick:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

---

This code works for me:

```
from math import sqrt
from random import uniform


sum2 = 0
size = 0
while size < 100000:
    x1 = uniform(-1, 1)
    y1 = uniform(-1, 1)
    x2 = uniform(-1, 1)
    y2 = uniform(-1, 1)
    z1 = uniform(-1, 1)
    z2 = uniform(-1, 1)

    r1 = sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2 + z1**2)
    r2 = sqrt(x2**2 + y2**2 + z2**2)
    if r1 > 1 or r2 > 1 or x1==y1==z1==0 or x2==y2==z2==0: continue
    size += 1
    x1 /= r1
    y1 /= r1
    z1 /= r1
    x2 /= r2
    y2 /= r2
    z2 /= r2
    sum2 += sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2 + (z1 - z2) ** 2)
print(sum2/size)
```

Output was:

```
1.3337880809331075
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have added a new code in the question which uses rejection sampling to reject all points lying outside the sphere, yet it doesn't quite give the desired result. Please check the edit.

Comment: The rejection sampling will reduce the number of usable points. Instead of 10000, you'll only get `4/3*pi/8*10000 = 5236` on average, so there will be more deviation in the result. But I don't see anything wrong with your code. Instead of iterating a fixed number of times, you could continue looping until you have 10000 usable points.

Comment: I have tried it with 10^6 and 10^7 iterations as well. It just goes on to converge to 1.25 as the sample size increases.

Comment: See the latest addition to my answer for the code. The output appears to converge to 4 / 3

Comment: That's weird. It's nearly the same code, yet it gives a different result. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Comment: Okay I realized my mistake. Every time I divide x1 by sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2 + z1**2) in my code, I also change the value of norm, so I divide y1 and z1 by a different norm than x1 and hence the overall incorrect result. It's embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

As explained the random sampling of this small MC simulation is not done in the proper way.

You want to extract random point uniformly distributed on the surface of the sphere. The easyest way to do so is to use polar coordinates and the choose randomly the angle theta (in 0-pi) and phi (in 0-2pi).

If you want to mantain the cartesian coordinates you have to transform your distribution using the known transformation matrix from cartesian to 3-d polar coordinate system.

Comment: I think you mean spherical coordinates, but these won't work either, because a point is more likely to be chosen near the z-axis compared to the x,y plane:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

The probability distribution has to choose points even over the area of the sphere.

Comment: I had thought of that method. But then I learnt you will get more density near the poles.

Comment: Yes usually in physics we use to call polar coordinates also the spherical ones.
In the first link you have posted. Here is a link on how to pick random points on a sphere. Obviously one angle has to be choosen uniformly in the (0,2pi) range, the other one has to undergo a cosine transformation to keep the density uniform.
If u and v are uniform in (0,1) then you can obtain theta and phi like this:
theta = 2*pi*u
phi = arccos(2*v-1)
r = 1 since sphere is unitary
[link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html)